# About Usage of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, u) $ be a measure space, $f$ and each
$f_n$ be integrable and non-negative, $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e. and $\lim \int f_n$ = $ \int f.
$
Prove that for each measurable set $A \in \mathcal{M} $,
$\lim \int_A f_n$ = $ \int_Af$

My attempt : Here, I first define $g_n = f_n \chi_A $ and $g = f\chi_A$. Of course, $\lim g_n$ = $ g$ a.e. since $\lim f_n$ = $ f$. Also, $g_n \leq 2f$, where f is integrable, by dominated convergence theorem we can put lim inside and get the result : $\lim \int g_n$ = $\lim \int_A f_n$ = $ \int g$ = $ \int_Af$

My question is the following : I am note sure if $2f$ dominates $g_n$s and also I wonder where we will use the fact that $\lim \int f_n$ = $ \int f.
$ ? I will be glad if you help

Comment: Yes the domination $g_n \leq 2f$ is doubtful. Instead, you can use the [Generalized Lebesgue Dominated Convergence](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-generalized-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem) where only $g_n \leq f_n$ is necessary.

Comment: You argue as contained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292463/on-the-convergence-of-a-specific-sequence-of-integrable-functions).

Comment: Or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386401/almost-complete-proof-that-int-a-f-n-to-int-a-f).